# I get null values while adding on the same index of an array

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

Hey i was trying to recognize numbers from a string and convert them into a String array, but with this code what i get is:

> IE:    [null1, null2, exc..]

I dont know how to take out this null value.
I also would like to find a way to do this, without an array, because i should increase its length manually.

Any tips? Thanks!

```
public class ProvaToArray {
    public static void main(String[] x) {
        String s = "1-2-3-4-lorem23ip567um1";
        String[] ris = toArray(s);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ris)); //should printout  [1, 2, 3, 4, 23, 567, 1]
    }

    public static String[] toArray(String s){
        String[] l = new String[10];
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++){
            if(estNumber(s.charAt(i) + "")){
                l[count] += "" + s.charAt(i);
                if(!estNumber(s.charAt(i+1) + "")){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(i+1 == s.length()-1){
                if(estNumber(s.charAt(i+1) + "")){
                    l[count] = "" + s.charAt(i+1);
                }
            }
        }
        return l;
    }

    public static boolean estNumber(String i){
        if(i.matches("^-?\\d+$"))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you initialize your String array :

```
String[] l = new String[10];
```

Each index contains null.

When you append a String to that null, you get the String "null" append to your String.

If you change :

```
l[count] += "" + s.charAt(i);
```

to

```
if (l[count] == null)
    l[count] = "" + s.charAt(i);
else
    l[count] += "" + s.charAt(i);
```

You'll get rid of the "null" String.

I saw the code you posted as an answer. It shouldn't be posted as an answer if it doesn't answer the question. You should have added it to the question.

Anyway, your problem is accessing the `i+2`'th character of the String s, which leads to IndexOutOfBoundsException in the final iteration of your loop.
Instead of checking the `i`'th, `i+1`'th and `i+2`'th character in the same iteration, you should check one character in each iteration, and use a local variable to hold the current number.

Your code can be much simpler than it currently is :

```
public static String[] toArray(String s)
{
    ArrayList<String> m = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder currentNumber = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
            currentNumber.append (s.charAt(i));
        } else {
            if (currentNumber.length() > 0) {
                m.add(currentNumber.toString());
                currentNumber.setLength(0);
            }
        }
    }
    if (currentNumber.length() > 0) {
        m.add(currentNumber.toString());
    }                    
    return m.toArray(new String[m.size()]);
}
```

This produces the array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 23, 567, 1]` for the input you used.

Comment: Awesome thanks! But if i dont want to use a String[], but an arrayList? how can i get rid of this?

Comment: @Benny If you use an ArrayList, you must either call `list.add("" + s.charAt(i))` or `list.set(count,list.get(count) + s.charAt(i));` depending on whether or not you already added an element to the `count` index of the List. You'll still need a condition.

Comment: My real problem is to add it on the same index in the arrayList.. i tried with set, add, but still cant manage it

Comment: @Benny `list.set(count,list.get(count) + s.charAt(i));` should work, as long as `list.size()>count`.

Comment: it throws  IndexOutOfBoundExceptions. Dont understand why

Comment: @Benny It would throw that if `list.size()<=count`.

Comment: i'll try to work with it, even if i put a condition, it doesn't work.. thanks anyway

Comment: i find out that the problem is to use the set, i first need to add an element..thats why it throws that exception. So any other tips on how to use that?

Comment: @Benny That's what I wrote in my first comment.